# Can't type caret ('^') in Konsole

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, kde, konsole

I can obviously type it my browser and even in Xterm, but not in Konsole.  I'm using Kubuntu, 13.10. To be thorough, I am using a German keyboard (which is already a pain), but I don't see why that should matter.  In Konsole, I can type the other character ('°') on the same key.

I use this all the time in vim and it's annoying to copy and paste it.  I saw something similar [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64634/cannot-type-accented-capital-letters-in-kde-konsole), but it wasn't solved.  One of the answers asked if the problem was reproduced in kate; it is.

I could use another terminal emulator, I guess, but it would be nice to use Konsole.

Comment: What happens if you type `^` twice or `^` and ` ` (space)? Did you research on the web a bit before you posted your Q here?

Comment: Nice.  The `^` and then space works.  Thanks.  I did search the web, but I was spelling caret wrong, and using `^` in my search gave me nothing.

Comment: You should also consider upgrading 13.10 is not supported since July 17.

Comment: I upgrade my OSs like I pay my taxes: late or never.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been many discussions about dead keys, how they should be used to be able to generate accented characters, etc. The behaviour of characters such as `~` and `^` may depend on your system's locale settings and the input method of the specific program.

I personally find [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xkeyboard-config/+bug/73240) interesting.

If you hit a special character's key and nothing happens, chances are that the system is waiting whether you mean to input an accented character. Hitting  (space) should usually get you the character itself.